# Xslt for table content replacement only in Tbody

Tags: xslt

Could you please help us out in the below scenario.
We need xsl code for the below scenario.

We need to retrieve ref tag inside para in Thead
We need to remove ref tag inside para in Tbody.
For last cell we should not perform this ref removal. ie) should behave like thead

### Sample Input:

```
<xml>
<Table>
    <thead>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <para id=4> 
                    <ref>A</ref>
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <para id=1> 
                    <ref>b</ref>
                </para>
            </Cell>
            .
            .
            <Cell>
                <para id=6> 
                    <ref>retrive</ref>
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <para id=2> 
                    c
                </para>
            </Cell>
            .
            .
            <Cell>
                <para id=7> 
                    <ref>retrive</ref>
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell >
                <para id=3> 
                    <ref>d</ref>
                    <ref>e</ref>
                </para>
            </Cell>
            .
            .
            <Cell>
                <para id=8> 
                    <ref>retrive</ref>
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Expected Output:

```
   <xml>
  <Table>
    <thead>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <para id=4> 
                    <ref>A</ref>   (No change in thead)
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <para id=1>   (para attribute should be retrieved)
                    b    (ref tag should be removed but content should be retrieved)
                </para>
            </Cell>
            .
            .
            <Cell>
                <para id=6> 
                    <ref>retrieve</ref>  (Should retrieve ref tag with value)
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <para id=2> 
                    c
                </para>
            </Cell>
            .
            .
            <Cell>
                <para id=7> 
                    <ref>retrieve</ref>  (Should retrieve ref tag with value)
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Cell>
                <para id=3> 
                    d
                    e
                </para>
            </Cell>
            .
            .
            <Cell>
                <para id=8> 
                    <ref>retrieve</ref>  (Should retrieve ref tag with value)
                </para>
            </Cell>
        </Row>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to show the XSLT you have tried so far. In your previous question the answer mentioned about the XSLT identity template, so you can build upon that. You would just need an extra template to remove the `ref` elements you don't want. Also, can you make sure your XML samples are well-formed. Your opening `Table` tag does not match the closing tag of `table`, and your attributes need to be surrounded with quotation marks. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for your response.I will make sure evrything is fine before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the adjustments to your input XML to have the closing table tag match the opening table tag and to wrap the value of id in quotation marks, the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="no"
encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="tbody/Row/Cell[position()!=last()]/para/ref">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

when applied to this corrected input XML produces the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Table>
  <thead>
    <Row>
     <Cell>
        <para id="4">
           <ref>A</ref>
        </para>
     </Cell>
   </Row>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <Row>
     <Cell>
        <para id="1">b</para>
     </Cell>
     <Cell>
        <para id="6">
           <ref>retrieve</ref>
        </para>
     </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
     <Cell>
        <para id="2"> 
                c
            </para>
     </Cell>
     <Cell>
        <para id="7">
           <ref>retrieve</ref>
        </para>
     </Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
     <Cell>
        <para id="3">de</para>
     </Cell>
     <Cell>
        <para id="8">
           <ref>retrieve</ref>
        </para>
     </Cell>
    </Row>
  </tbody>
</Table>
```

The `<xsl:template match="tbody/Row/Cell[position()!=last()]/para/ref">`
matches all `Cell` elements in `tbody` except the last one - `position()!=last()` -  and replace the `ref` attribute with its value.