# Issue in integarting two xslt templates rowmerge and tag removal

Tags: xslt

```
We have two diffrent scenario we got answers in the forum
```

[Xslt for table content replacement only in Tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28111641/xslt-for-table-content-replacement-only-in-tbody)

(We need to retrieve ref tag inside para in Thead We need to remove ref tag inside para in Tbody. For last cell we should not perform this ref removal. ie) should behave like thead)

[writing xslt for the below scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105881/writing-xslt-for-the-below-scenario)

(Rule: for merged rows: copy content of primary merged cell to other cells in merged rows.)
    But while integrating/testing we have a problem. after integrating we are not getting the expected output.ie) Tag removel is done on the first row but in the merged row it is noit heppening.
Could someone help us in this regard.

## Sample Input:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TABLE align="CENTER" >
    <THEAD editable="T">
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No </Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment</Para></CELL> 
        </ROW>
    </THEAD>
    <TBODY editable="T">
        <ROW editable="F">
           <CELL rowmerged="T" ><Para appdisplaytext=" "><refint>S.No1 </refint>  </Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name1</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">  <refint>Role1</refint></Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment1</Para>   </CELL> 
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="T" ><Para appdisplaytext=" "></Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name2</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role2</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment2</Para>  </CELL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No 3</Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name3</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" "><refint>Role3</refint></Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment3</Para></CELL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No 4</Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name4</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role4</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment4</Para></CELL> 
        </ROW>
       </TBODY>
     </TABLE>
```

## XSLT Tried:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
     <xsl:output method="xml"  omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
      <xsl:template match="table">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="TBODY/ROW/CELL[position()!=last()]/Para/refint">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="//TABLE//Para[not(normalize-space())][../@rowmerged='T']">
          <xsl:variable name="cellnum" select="count(../preceding-sibling::CELL) + 1"/>
          <xsl:variable name="matchingCells" select="               ../../preceding-sibling::ROW/CELL[$cellnum]/Para"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="$matchingCells[normalize-space()][last()]"/>
         </xsl:template>
       </xsl:transform>
```

## Expected Output:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <TABLE align="CENTER" >
     <THEAD editable="T">
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No </Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment</Para></CELL> 
        </ROW>
      </THEAD>
      <TBODY editable="T">
        <ROW editable="F">
           <CELL rowmerged="T" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No1 </Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name1</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role1</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment1</Para></CELL> 
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="T" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No1 </Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name2</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role2</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment2</Para></CELL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No 3</Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name3</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role3</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment3</Para></CELL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No 4</Para></CELL>
            <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name4</Para></CELL>
              <CELL rowmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role4</Para></CELL>
            <CELL colmerged="F" ><Para appdisplaytext=" " >Comment4</Para></CELL> 
        </ROW>
        </TBODY>
       </TABLE>
```

## we got:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <TABLE align="CENTER">
        <THEAD editable="T">
        <ROW editable="F">
        <CELL rowmerged="F"><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No </Para></CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"> <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name</Para></CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"> <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role</Para></CELL>
        <CELL colmerged="F"><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Comment</Para></CELL>
        </ROW>
        </THEAD>
        <TBODY editable="T">
        <ROW editable="F">
        <CELL rowmerged="T"><Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No1 </Para></CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name1</Para></CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F"><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role1</Para></CELL>
        <CELL colmerged="F"><Para appdisplaytext=" ">Comment1</Para></CELL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
        <CELL rowmerged="T"><Para appdisplaytext=" "><refint>S.No1 </refint> </Para>      </CELL>      (We are getting ref int here.)
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name2</Para>      </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role2</Para>      </CELL>      
        <CELL colmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Comment2</Para>      </CELL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No 3</Para>      </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name3</Para>      </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role3</Para>      </CELL>
        <CELL colmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Comment3</Para>      </CELL>
        </ROW>
        <ROW editable="F">
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">S.No 4</Para>      </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Name4</Para>      </CELL>
        <CELL rowmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Role4</Para>      </CELL>
        <CELL colmerged="F">        <Para appdisplaytext=" ">Comment4</Para>      </CELL>
        </ROW>
        </TBODY>
        </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs in this template

```
 <xsl:template match="//TABLE//Para[not(normalize-space())][../@rowmerged='T']">
  <xsl:variable name="cellnum" select="count(../preceding-sibling::CELL) + 1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="matchingCells" select="../../preceding-sibling::ROW/CELL[$cellnum]/Para"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$matchingCells[normalize-space()][last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

When you match an "empty" `Para` element, where `rowmerged` is "T", then you copy the corresponding `Para` from the preceding `ROW`. But because you are using `xsl:copy-of` this will copy it without any further transformation. `xsl:copy-of` copies from the input tree, and does not take into account any transformation you may previously done on that node (which is in the output, not the input).

Try using `xsl:apply-templates` instead:

```
 <xsl:template match="//TABLE//Para[not(normalize-space())][../@rowmerged='T']">
  <xsl:variable name="cellnum" select="count(../preceding-sibling::CELL) + 1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="matchingCells" select="../../preceding-sibling::ROW/CELL[$cellnum]/Para"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$matchingCells[normalize-space()][last()]"/>
 </xsl:template>
```

By using `xsl:apply-templates` it will apply any transforms on the nodes you are selecting at this point.

**EDIT:** If you only want to copy the children of the `Para` node, try this template which copies the `Para` node being matched, but copies the children from the previous sibling.

```
 <xsl:template match="//TABLE//Para[not(normalize-space())][../@rowmerged='T']">
  <xsl:variable name="cellnum" select="count(../preceding-sibling::CELL) + 1"/>
  <xsl:variable name="matchingCells" select="../../preceding-sibling::ROW/CELL[$cellnum]/Para"/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$matchingCells[normalize-space()][last()]/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your answer.It is working but we need to copy only the content of para tag not the full para tag from original